# Setup Django on Win 7 Wamp

Tags: python, django, 64-bit, wamp

I've followed and tried many different things here, but am stuck on getting my `settings.py` to load.  Also, during my search for an answer I learned about "Embedded" and "Daemon" setups and I fear that the setup path I am heading down will require I restart Apache every time I update code.  Is there any way to fix the following setup so I can start developing a Django site? and without the need to restart Apache every time?

The error I am receiving is:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'brett.app.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named brett.app.settings
```

I know that python is working because I have a test.py script that echos "Hello World!".  I believe Django is working and python can find it because the above error is occurring from within a Django call stack (`\django\conf\__init__.py`).  Also, I've tried forward slashes, backward slashes, and every variant of directory in the `sys.path.append` statement.

**What's installed:**

```
Windows 7 Ultimate x64
WAMP 2.2 x64
Apache 2.2.21
Python 2.7.3 AMD64
mod_wsgi 3.3 AMD64 py2.7 (from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
```

**How it's configured:**

*C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*

```
127.0.0.1       brett.local
```

*C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi .py
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName brett.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/brett"
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/brett">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/wamp/www/brett/apache/apache.wsgi"    
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/brett/apache">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*C:\wamp\brett\apache\apache.wsgi*

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('c:\\wamp\\www')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'brett.app.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: I opted not to use the Django server since I couldn't/haven't found any good info on configuring multiple sites and local urls.  When working with wamp I like to setup different hosts for each site like `brett.local`, `clientA.local`, etc.  Also, I don't really like having to both start wamp and something on the command line just to get a server running.

Answer (score 0):

To see if you have django installed you can execute python (if it's not in your environment it should be somwehere like: `C:/pythonXX/python.exe`) and type:

`import django`

Additionally for python development it is best to use build in django server.  This can be started by `python manage.py runserver`.  It will just give you one less thing to have to configure to get developing.  It is lightweight, reboots automatically and single threaded.

Comment: Both work.  As for Django server see my comment on main post.

Answer (score 0):

1. This has nothing to do with Embedded vs Demon mode.
2. If you're just starting out developing a site, why are you mucking around with Apache? Use the development server via `manage.py runserver`, that's what it's for.
3. You haven't shown your project layout, but the error message is showing you that it can't find the Python path brett.app.settings. Do you have a `settings.py` in `c:\wamp\www\brett\app\`?

Comment: I have the default project files in `\brett\app\` including `settings.py`.  I opted for using apache so I can start wamp (one click) without having to open a shell or other window and type command line to start django server.  See main post for comment on using Django server.